# how to get sub string in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have following list which i need to parse in django template.

```
['000.223.4.00/24|Network a', '000.000.00.0/25|Network b', '10.000.1.0/24|Network c']
```

Basically, i want to separate network and network name part already separated by '|'. Any idea of how to achieve it in django. I had been doing it with indexof() and substring methods in jquery. looking for a similar thing.

Comment: Why not finding them in backend not frontend?

Comment: That is always an option but I believe such tweaking should be done at browser end.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in django templates using built in tags and filters.

The right way to do it - parse it in view by python code and pass it to template as list of separated items.

But if it is principal for you to do it in django templates - you can write custom template filter.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

Comment: Thank you, i just wanted to know if there are any built-in tags to achieve this.